# emacs orgmode -- how to export html file to other directory instead of the same directory with .org file

Tags: org-mode, emacs24

`emacs 24.2.1 and org mode version 8.0.3`,Although I have referred to the resolution in [Emacs Org-mode - Export to another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559753/emacs-org-mode-export-to-another-directory), add below statement to the .org file directly. after pressing `C-c C-e h o`,the .html file still come to the current directory.

```
#+bind: org-export-publishing-directory  "~/org/exported_html/"
```

and i have also tried to add below statement to .emacs file. but still not work out what i want.

```
(setq org-export-publishing-directory "~/org/exported_html")
```

anyone who can give me an advice? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The var you're using is for *publishing*. What you do with C-c C-e is *exporting* (unless you then press P or such for publishing "projects"). I *think* your Org file must be part of a project, and then your variable would make sense. Not 100% sure, to be further tested.

Comment: thanks, maybe the exported file included into a project first is the only method.thanks for your tip..