# in org-mode, how to specify name of exported file?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

In org-mode, when I export to PDF or HTML, I'd like to specify the names of the resulting files. Ideally two separate names, one for the PDF, one for the HTML. Is this possible?

Comment: I posted a workaround here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34645/3871

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** For newer versions of org-mode, see [slondr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64563122/354577).

---

[It doesn't look like you can specify a name for the exported file as a whole](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html#fn-4).

From the link, emphasis mine:

> When exporting only a subtree, each of the previous keywords can be overriden locally by special node properties. These begin with ‘EXPORT_’, followed by the name of the keyword they supplant. For example, ‘DATE’ and ‘OPTIONS’ keywords become, respectively, ‘EXPORT_DATE’ and ‘EXPORT_OPTIONS’ properties. **Subtree export also supports the self-explicit ‘EXPORT_FILE_NAME’ property [4]**.
>
> **[4] There is no buffer-wide equivalent for this property**. The file name in this case is derived from the file associated to the buffer, if possible, or asked to the user otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Chris's answer is out of date. There is now [an `EXPORT_FILE_NAME` setting](https://orgmode.org/manual/Export-Settings.html#Export-Settings):

```
#+export_file_name: <filename>
```

If you put this at the start of your file (not in a subtree), it will name the entire file that when you export.